# Vue image size filter

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js, image-size

I'm trying to solve an issue for pulling/scraping images from **URL** with PHP (Codeigniter 3), so whenever I get them, sometimes there are too many and often very small and useless.  I've tried countless times to make a Vue filter or PHP code snippet to select only those image urls that have image size bigger than 150x150. PHP gets very slow and I wouldn't bother with it. The last thing I tried was with jquery:

```
Vue.filter('imagesize', (url) => {
  var tmpImg = new Image()
  tmpImg.src = url
  $(tmpImg).one('load', () => {
    if (tmpImg.width > 150) { 
      return url
    }
  })
})
```

First of all it doesn't work, but also loading 30 images would be slow as well for a filter. My question is: Can I **scrape better** these images with vue or any JS, then keep only the larger ones, or use some **other filter**, or maybe **hide** smaller ones **after I render** them ? Please any suggestions would be highly appreciated .

Comment: You are passing an url and then returning the same url, what was it supposed to do?

Comment: I hope you know how VueJS filters work, or maybe I'm wrong somewhere. The filter passes through only those image URLs that meet the condition, in this case width bigger than 150 px. This filter is put on v-for loop that passes through all URLs received from the RSS post link.

Comment: From the official docs: `...The filter function takes a value as the argument and returns the transformed value...` if you want to filter in the coffee sense, you should do it with a function not a filter.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, there is a filter, called filterBy, which does what you want. I'll elaborate in the answer. (Yo Dawg, I heard you like filters, so we put a filter in a filter so you can filter while you filter)

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering on a single value (the URL) what you should really do is filter on the array of URLs the same way the filter filter is implemented.
Have a look at the source code where I removed the boring parts:

```
export function filterBy (arr, search, delimiter) {
  ... stuff ...
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    ... stuff ...
      if (/*some condition items must pass*/) { // <-- here you put the condition on size
          res.push(item)
    ... stuff ...
  return res
}
```

Comment: You are right, a function is better choice than filter. Any type of **JS logic** for this matter would be appreciated. I get image urls from ajax request and have to clean them somehow. Vue.js has build-in filterby that you mention, yet is useless for async onload function that I have to use to get each image. I got one solution with  JS promises, will test it and share it if it works.